# win32ui insert an image to CreateDC()

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, pywin32, win32ui

I'm trying to print a receipt using a thermal printer, this is the best solution I got so far using win32ui but I need to insert a logo or QR code

```
import win32ui

doc = open("1.txt", 'r').readlines()
f = 50
dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
dc.CreatePrinterDC()
dc.StartDoc('Test')
dc.StartPage()


for i, text in enumerate(doc):
    print(i, text)
    dc.TextOut(0,i*f, text)
    dc.MoveTo(0, i*f)

dc.EndPage()
```

Answer (score 0):

*PyWin32* homepage: [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32).

After "a bit" of researching:

- [[ME.TimGolden]: Print](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) (and related pages)
- [[ReadTheDocs.Pillow]: ImageWin Module (Windows-only)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageWin.html#imagewin-module-windows-only)
- [[MS.Docs]: Windows GDI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/windows-gdi)
- Other resources

I was able to come up with a dummy example (it also uses [[PyPI]: Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow) - I wanted to use it just for reading the images (also tried *OpenCV*), but in the end it does almost all the work).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

import win32con as wcon
import win32print as wprn
import win32ui as wui
from PIL import Image as pil_image, ImageWin as pil_image_win


def add_txt(hdc, file_name, new_page=False):
    if new_page:
        hdc.StartPage()
    pixel_scale = 84
    with open(file_name, mode="r") as fin:
        for idx, line in enumerate(fin):
            print("Text line {:d}: {:s}".format(idx, line))
            hdc.TextOut(5, idx * pixel_scale, line)
    if new_page:
        hdc.EndPage()


def draw_img(hdc, dib, maxh, maxw):
    w, h = dib.size
    print("Image HW: ({:d}, {:d}), Max HW: ({:d}, {:d})".format(h, w, maxh, maxw))
    h = min(h, maxh)
    w = min(w, maxw)
    l = (maxw - w) // 2
    t = (maxh - h) // 2
    dib.draw(hdc, (l, t, l + w, t + h))


def add_img(hdc, file_name, new_page=False):
    if new_page:
        hdc.StartPage()
    maxw = hdc.GetDeviceCaps(wcon.HORZRES)
    maxh = hdc.GetDeviceCaps(wcon.VERTRES)
    img = pil_image.open(file_name)
    dib = pil_image_win.Dib(img)
    draw_img(hdc.GetHandleOutput(), dib, maxh, maxw)
    if new_page:
        hdc.EndPage()


def main(*argv):
    printer_name = "Microsoft Print to PDF"  #wprn.GetDefaultPrinter()
    out_file = ".\\test.pdf"
    #out_file = None  # Send to printer directly
    hdc = wui.CreateDC()
    hdc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
    if out_file and os.path.isfile(out_file):
        os.unlink(out_file)
    hdc.StartDoc("Test", out_file)
    add_txt(hdc, "in.txt")
    add_img(hdc, "qr.jpg")
    hdc.EndDoc()
    hdc.DeleteDC()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- To avoid printing each time I ran the program (and there were lots of them), I "printed" to a *.pdf*
- I centered the image in the *.pdf* page (in a dummy manner) only considering printable area (ignoring printer physical properties, V / H scaling, ...). A robust (production ready) implementation should take all into account, fact that will make it waay more complex

  - The above also applies to text (and other possible elements that might be added in the future). For example, a long line should be truncated in order for it not to go outside printable area

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073175487]> dir /b *.pdf
> File Not Found
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073175487]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Text line 0: 1st dummy line
>
> Text line 1: 2nd dummy longer line - The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog - The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog - The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>
> Text line 2: 3rd dummy line
>
> Image HW: (1200, 1200), Max HW: (7016, 4961)
>
> Done.
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073175487]> dir /b *.pdf
> test.pdf
> ```

The generated *test.pdf*:

[image: Img0]

And a page from my (*Epson*) printer (with `out_file = None`). Colors are a bit off as black is very low and it attempted to synthetize it from *CMY* (and also it's late night and the phone that I took the picture with is old):

[image: Img1]

You could check [[SO]: Square in Python GDI (with PatBLT) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71283035/4788546) for another *GDI* example from *Python* (and *PyWin32*).

Comment: How can someone be that nice on stackoverflow ? :D 
thank you! but I have a problem to printing this to thermal printer it won't print on any printer either except "Microsoft Print to PDF" also the pdf file will be damaged if i choose any other printer

Comment: As I said I only tested with this printer. For other printers there's no *.pdf* file only a document. Check *out\_file* initialization (commented out). I don't have a clue what a thermal printer is, but I can give it a shot on a regular one.

Comment: Tank you @KJ for the explanation. So no reason for a thermal printer not to behave like a regular one.

Comment: Ok so the code would behave differently on a thermal printer and on a regular one? And that would be due to the image (meaning that text behaves the same) - talking in the *GDI* (*DC*) context?