# Can't print image

Tags: python, winapi, printing, pywin32

Faced such a problem. The image is created and saved, everything is correct, but I can't print it automatically. What could be the problem?

P.S. I tried to save the file in PDF format, it is printed automatically, but on the entire A4 sheet, but I need it without changing the scale.

My code:

```
import win32api
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

img = Image.new("RGB", (300, 250), 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
sticker_text = 'Name\nSurname\n\nCompany'
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=40)
_, _, w, h = draw.textbbox((0, 0), sticker_text, font=font)
draw.text(((300 - w) / 2, (250 - h) / 2), sticker_text, font=font, fill='black', align='center')
img.save('link_to_file.jpg')

file = "link_to_file.jpg"

win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", file, None, ".", 0)
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I suggest you could try to [use GDI to print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/how-to--print-using-the-gdi-print-api) instead of `ShellExecut`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73430724/4788546

Comment: @KJ Wow, thanks, it's working, but it prints full A4. Can I config this? I need 100% scale of image.

Comment: Thank you all guys. Keep trying to config smth.